# Can we write multiple calling functions in ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I know that we can give multiple classes in class directive by giving one space after declaring a class.In the same way can we write multiple passing elements and calling functions in the ng-click directive?

Comment: Answer from @Sachiila ranawaka will serve your purpose but beware of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) concept. This type of calls are not recommended.

Comment: please dont do it.. write third function and call that one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options :

1. Create a third method that wrap both methods. Advantage here is that
   you put less logic in your template.
2. Otherwise if you want to add 2 calls in ng-click you can add ';' after method1('test') like this

   ```
   ng-click="method1('test'); method2('first','second');"
   ```

   See here : http://jsfiddle.net/banshi/5kwn0an8/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to call multiple functions at a time

```html
<button ng-click="method1(); method2();">
  Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. separate two functions by semicolon

`<div ng-click="functionOne();functionTwo()"> </div>`

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.functionOne = function() {
      console.log("functionOne")
    }
    $scope.functionTwo = function() {
      console.log("functionTwo")
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-click="functionOne();functionTwo();"> click</div>
</div>
```